# Usage of ThreadStatic (Unit Testing)

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I have written the following to stub a Singleton for the purpose of unit testing.

```
 public static class LocalisationSetter
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static CultureInfo _cultureInfo;

        public static void Set(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            _cultureInfo = cultureInfo;

            Localisation.Current.Culture = _cultureInfo; // Setting The singleton.
        }
    }
```

In my test I do something like below:

```
LocalisationSetter.Set(new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

The above method just seems little "dirty"...

Just wondered if there is potentially a better way. I need to make sure the changes to "Localisation" is only visible to the thread.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if `Localisation.Current` is not `ThreadStatic` also then your `Setter` class is pointless.  Even if it is, the class doesn't do anything that you couldn't do straight from the test.

Comment: Can you clarify if there's something about this that is specific to unit testing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't just set the thread's current culture? That is `Thread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;` Also `Thread.CurrentUICulture`.

Answer (score 3):

Having a class that is a "Setter" is a fairly peculiar pattern. As DStanley commented, the above will not work as expected without Making `Localization.Current` thread-static, too:

```
public class Localization{

   [ThreadStatic]
   private static Localization _current;

   public static Current {
     get { _current = _current ?? new Localization(); return _current }
     set { _current = value; }
   }
}
```

That being said, this is generally a very peculiar pattern, as this is effectively creating "global" variables, which generally makes unit testing, and software maintenance more complicated.

(The above code creates ephemeral state that could change at any time, impacting the behavior of your code).

Consider using dependency injection, or at a minimum, organizing these "global" variables into a few aggregate objects so that the fact that you do have these context objects around is easier to track.

Comment: I thought if the "global" refers to a thread static instance then each thread will get its own copy. This way each test can run in isolation. Thanks!

Comment: @msuhash, It's true that ThreadStatic will isolate this per thread, but the point of my answer was that you're creating shared state and not passing it via normal conventions (i.e. method calls/passing objects). This is *probably* a code smell, and should be avoided.